# Adding a class to a button on every row of a datagrid button

Tags: jquery, datagrid, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
$("input[type=submit]").addClass("btn btn-success");
```

I want to add this class to a datagrid button:

```
<asp:EditCommandColumn CancelText="Cancel " ButtonType="PushButton" EditText="Items">
</asp:EditCommandColumn>
```

But it adds the class to every submit button on the page obviously.

can i add an id to this line like `$("#id input[type=submit]").addClass("btn btn-success");`??

it renders like this in the chrome dev console

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNames$ctl02$ctl00" value="Select" class="btn btn-success">
```

Nothing really seems to work for me

Comment: what is id of main gridview?

Comment: Why don't you set class server side???

Comment: id is dgNames, no need to touch code behind.

Comment: Wolff suggestion seems the suitable approach, I think in web forms, you are supposed to code client side only when you can't do it server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your selector more specific. Are all the buttons you want to add classes to under the Grid ?

Then your selector should be 
//assuming your asp:Grid has an id like "myGrid", your selector should look like

```
$("#myGrid input[type=submit]").addClass("btn btn-success");
```

You were adding the class to all the buttons in the page because that's what you asked jQuery to do. With the line above, you are telling it to add the class only to input controls of type submit that have myGrid as an ancestor in the DOM tree.

Comment: ahh i see now, the code snippet above doesnt work, but this does  $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNames input[type=submit]").addClass("btn btn-success"); sorry i should of explained i was using a master and content page, but thanks for all the help @Veverke